# How to get date/time of request sent and response received for each thread in any listener in jmeter

Tags: request, jmeter, response, latency

I would like to have time/date of request sent to server, response received by client and latency  by each thread in JMeter.

Any possibility to achieve this in non-gui mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `time/date of request sent to server` - JMeter stores this already in form of [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), just in case you would like to change it to another format - it's controllable via `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format`. It defaults to `ms` (time in milliseconds from the beginning of Unix epoch) however you can amend it by providing a [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern instead
2. `response received by client` - by default JMeter doesn't store this to reduce memory footprint and disk IO however you can enable storing the response by setting the following properties:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```
3. `latency` - JMeter stores it by default, if it doesn't - make sure to set the following property:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
   ```
4. Once you apply the above configurations [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t your.test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
5. When your test finishes you will be able to see the metrics and the response in the `result.jtl` file (which is basically XML file) either using your favorite XML editor or using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

References:

- [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score -1):

Those values will be in output csv you can generate adding:

> -l results.csv

You can generate the html report adding:

> -e -o report_folder

So you would end up with:

> jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.csv -e -o report_folder